# Inject values from HashiCorp Vault into JEE-Appllication (WAR File)

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, properties, devops, hashicorp-vault

We have an old Weblogic based infrastructure with classic JEE-Applications inside. Applications a deployed as WAR-files using Atlassian Bamboo as CD/CI deployment pipeline.

There are multiple stages - DEV, TEST, PROD etc. We have a HashiCorp Vault Server where all the stage dependent variables are stored. We cannot use Vault Server at runtime, because it is not high available (yet).

I want to load all the variables from the Vault Server inside the deployment pipeline and inject them into the WAR-file before uploading to WebLogic. The values must be statically injected once during deployment, no dynamic update is required.

Inside the application the values are referenced using ${value} notation inside the application.yaml (as it usually happens in Spring and Spring-Boot application). For Example:

```
configuration:
    azure.app.client_id: ${AZURE_APP_CLIENT_ID:1234567890}
```

What is the best way to replace all the placeholders using real values loading them from HashiCorp Vault?

Answer (score 1):

You will need access to the secrets during runtime and inject them as environment variables in your application's runtime. So I am assuming you have access to your Vault from your Bamboo pipeline.

You could write a file <env_name>.env in a path where your application can access it and add the file name in your spring config as an external config, which it will load and inject in all the right places, provided the names of your variables are matching the property file names. You will have to load the right file, based on the environment your application is running in.
But sometimes that is not the safest option if you have secrets (which you most likely do), since the file(s) is present and accessible to anyone who has access to the application's runtime.

The second options is to export the variables from your pipeline using something like -

`export AZURE_APP_CLIENT_ID="123123123"`

based on your environment, which means building a more environment specific logic into your pipeline and the deployable WAR remains independent of the environment.

Comment: Sorry, I have lot of questions. What is this env-file? What format is it? I know application.properties, it is the same? How can I export a full Hashicorp Directory in to this file?

Comment: application.properties or application.yml is one of the environment specific files. As I mentioned, you can create your own properties file and ask Spring Boot to use this in addition to the other files for environment specific configuration - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config